# Volume of an object obtained by rotating a region bounded by functions

Tags: integration, volume

The region bounded by $xy=1$ and $x=1, x=3, y=0$, rotated about $x=-1$.

I figured out the fact that I have to use Cylindrical Shell method, since

$$\int A_{outer} - A_{inner}$$ thing doesn't work in this case.

I'm still not sure how to use the Cylindrical Shell method. Can I just get the explanation of how to use the Cylindrical Shell method?

Comment: You *could* use Slicing, integrating with respect to $y$. But it would have to be done in two parts, from $y=0$ to $y=1/3$, and $y=1/3$ to $y=1$. Cylindrical Shells gives it to you in a single integral.

Comment: A very good way to solve volume integrations is to draw\plot the functions and shade the area you are going to transform...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V=2\pi\int_1^3(x+1)\frac1x\,dx$